# Athena Prepared Statement throws Exception when using Prepared Statements

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto, aws-sdk-java

I have the following query in Athena, I am using S3 as data store. I have 2 query parameters in the lambda expression.

```
PREPARE my_select1 FROM
    
SELECT address.phonenumbers FROM \"nested-query-db\".\"data_with_json1\" where 
cardinality(filter(address.phonenumbers,js->js.type = ? and js.number = ?)) >0 and 
cardinality(filter(address.phonenumbers,js->js.type = 'city'and js.number = '4')) > 0 and
firstname ='Emily';
```

When I execute it using

```
EXECUTE my_select1 USING 'Home', '1';
```

It throws the following error.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Query Failed to run with Error Message: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:1:
```

Sample Data:

```
{"firstname":"Emily","address":{"streetaddress":"101","city":"abc","state":"","phonenumbers":[{"type":"home","number":"11"},{"type":"city","number":"4"}]}}
```

Comment: The names of the statements are not aligned: my_select1 <> query_1_test.

Comment: That is typo, updated question

Comment: Could you share sample data please?

Comment: Hi Sample data:
{"firstname":"Emily","address":{"streetaddress":"101","city":"abc","state":"","phonenumbers":[{"type":"home","number":"11"},{"type":"city","number":"4"}]}}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be caused by the following.

You are probably using Athena engine version 2, which is [based on Presto](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/), explicitly Presto version [0.217](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html).

The PrestoDB Github repository identifies a very similar problem like the one you described in [this issue](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/16005).

The issue was addressed in PrestoDB by this [pull request](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/16184), and included in the [release 0.256](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/16296).

This means the fix is not included in Athena.

I am not sure if it will work, but to solve the issue you probably could try using [Athena engine version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference-0003.html), which is based on [Trino](https://trino.io/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

@jccampanero explain lambda expression does not support in Athena 2.

But I have a workaround for you.

This query works well, according your needs.

```
PREPARE my_select1 FROM
SELECT 
    address.phonenumbers
FROM address 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(address.phonenumbers) as t(phone)
where 
phone.type = ? and phone.number = ? and
cardinality(filter(address.phonenumbers, js -> js.type = 'city' and js.number = '4')) > 0 and
firstname = 'Emily';


EXECUTE my_select1 USING 'home', '11'
```